# VNC into a virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, vnc, vncserver

If I am running a virtual machine can I VNC into that machine? How can it be done?

Comment: I'm trying to VNC into the VM from the same machine that is running the VM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If I am running a virtual machine can I VNC into that machine?

Yes

> How can it be done?

Same way you VNC in to a physical machine. The VM is a computer in its own right, as long as you have the network set up correctly (eg bridged to your home network) it will work. If you have configured the VM to be on its own VM network it will not work.

Comment: In fact, other configurations than bridged (like NAT) will work but you'll need additional steps like port forwarding. http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15301